# O que significa infixr no Haskell

Tags: programação-funcional, haskell

O que é e para que serve esse infixr 3 &&?

```
infixr 3 &&
(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
True && True = True
_ && _ = False
```

Comment: Se voçe entende ingles, veja a resposta a esta pergunta:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770118/how-does-the-infix-work

Answer (score 6):

Notação infixada significa que o operador vem entre os operandos, por exemplo `1 + 1`. Funções em haskell geralmente utilizam notação posfixada, como por exemplo `pow 1 2`.

O `r` ou `l` se refere à associatividade, `r` para *right associativity* (associatividade à direita) e `l` para *left associativity* (associatividade à esquerda). Por exemplo, a operação seta é `infixr`, pois `A -> A -> A` significa `A -> (A -> A)`.

Mas também podemos utilizar apenas a notação `infix` e não fornecer a associaitividade, nesse caso se você tentar escrever um código utilizando várias vezes aquele operador sem parentesis, dará erro, pois o interpretador não saberá em que ordem interpretar.

No seu exemplo `True && True && True` será interpretado como `True && (True && True)`

O número se refere à precedência, quanto maior o número, maior a precedencia.